# How to Create an HTTP POST request from VB6?

Tags: post, vb6

I have a legacy system which is running VB6 which I use to gather sensitive customer data.  This data then needs to be passed to an internal web site.  I don't want to pass the data as GET variables on the URL.  I'd prefer to POST them.  I've spend many hours googling this issue, but I'm yet to find a solution.

How do I open a browser at a specific URL with POSTed variables from a VB6 application?

To confirm for all the people who are going to read this, the web page must open in a browser.  I don't want to parse the response from the web page in the VB6

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/174923/how-to-use-the-postdata-parameter-in-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the IE browser control, just place the parameters in the Postdata parameter of the Navigate method.  When the Navigate method is called, if the Postdata argument is empty, a GET is performed.  When the Postdata argument has data, a POST is performed.